# Loop through IDs with jQuery and make them droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've got a container `#itemGrid` and a few children-divs. They are all unique.
This is my code so far:

```
$('#grid-top').droppable({
     drop: dropHandler,
     accept: ".top"
});

$('#grid-assc').droppable({
    drop: dropHandler,
    accept: ".assc"
});
```

As you may see, they all only accepting the class which is in the ID of the element. I have some more divs I want to make droppable, but this is just too much work. How can I loop through these elements?

Comment: Every selector in JQuery creates an array. If you do `$('#itemGrid div').Droppable(...)` it will add droppable for each div inside itemgrid selector.. a loop is not needed.

Comment: @JFit I did this but know I want to add the feature that they only accept special classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#itemGrid div[id^=grid-]").each(function() {
    var accept = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $(this).droppable({
        drop: dropHandler,
        accept: "." + accept
    });
});
```